# parse: out + prepositional phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases, complementation, secondary-predicates

> By the time he was allowed (1) **out of his cupboard again**, the
>   summer holidays had started and Dudley had already broken his new
>   video camera, crashed his remote control airplane, and, first time (2)
>   **out on his racing bike**, knocked down old Mrs. Figg as she crossed Privet Drive on her crutches. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Do the highlighted phrases take roles of object and adjunct (adjective role) as noun phrases or as prepositional phrases; or (1) ‘out’ is an adjective and select prepositional phrase and they all becomes an direct object, (2) ‘out’ is an adjective and select prepositional phrase and they all becomes an post-modifier?

Comment: Your questions get harder and harder!  :-)

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, because I don’t know the meaning quite well is the reason of getting hard. For (1), I now think the construction: ‘they allowed [him out of his cupboard]’ So the bracketed part is a kind of nonfinite-clause. For (2) ‘out on his racing bike’ is a adjective phrase modifying first time.

Comment: In both cases, the sentences are elided:

[1] By the time he was allowed **to come** out of his cupboard again...   
[2] first time **he went** out on his racing bike...  

The words in **bold** font have been elided.

Comment: @BillFranke The perils of grammar! We all know exactly what it means; but we have three different ideas (all correct) of how it means it. I love this language.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, & this is one of the reasons I've said in past posts that grammar is trivial: in this case, it's a matter of what linguistic theory one's using. Because we know what it means & how to use the structure, it's not necessary to be able to explain how it means it, except for a grammar or linguistics test. This kind of question is too high-level for ELL: it belongs on EL&U because it requires a professional linguist to explain it. The terminology doesn't turn **me** on, but I'm happy to talk about the meaning without getting into the mechanisms of that meaning.

Comment: @BillFranke  Yah. Linguistics is like theology: fine, as long as you don't mistake it for religion. Gotta bring the bucket back to the wellhead. But I have to say that coming to grips with the New Grammar over the last six months on ELU and here have made me a better writer.

Comment: @Bill, StoneyB: I think the problem with this level of question is ELL answers are never going to standardise on one coherent set of analytical approaches or terminology, so in the end I'm not sure they're particularly useful here.

Comment: @StoneyB, your reply is the very tool that I can understand the sentences. And I need to correct a terminology. I just found that Bas Aarts calls the clause small clause - ex) Kate thinks [us clever].

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this is a great question (and upvoted), but I'm in agreement that it would probably be better served on EL&U. Does anyone know if we're going to be able to flag to suggest migration to EL&U anytime soon?

Comment: @WendiKidd, That's a good idea. I'm tired of this place that place thing. For learners, all is allowed, don't you think so. Yes, I can give you some point if you protect "Your" ELU, but what the goodness are you putting a bit in horses' mouths. How on the earth beginners can draw big picture. They only can walk step by step stumbling. Mines are all to be allowed, here at least. I don't go there, ELU, for your 'gag rule.' But leave me here freely to say, please!!

Comment: @Listenever Yeah, I think that's part of what we need to figure out in the beta period--what belongs on ELL and what belongs on ELU. I can understand that it could be confusing for learners--how are you to know where your question belongs when the community hasn't even decided yet?! But hopefully soon we will have a better consensus of what goes where, and a migration option would help with sorting questions out once we do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This prepositional phrase is, I think, best treated as a Subject(*he*)-related complement of the verb *allow*, which in this context means approximately *allow to go*; unpackage the passive form and it becomes an Object-related complement

   > [They] allowed him out of his cupboard ... [*out of his cupboard*] *is where they allowed him to go, so it is where he is located at the end of the clause.*
2. This is a little ambiguous. I'd read it as

   **a)** the fixed phrase *first time out*, meaning approximately ‘the first occasion on which one does or attempts something’; this is employed here as an adjunct of time; PLUS
    **b)** *on his racing bike* which modifies *first time out*, defining the something he attempted as riding his bike.

   Together, then, they constitute an adjunct to the clause *knocked down Mrs. Figg, &c*, defining it as occurring on the first occasion (that summer) when Dudley rode his bike.

Answer (score 3):

Those prepositions are used as **adverbs**, which happens now and then with prepositions. You can say *father is out*, to mean "father is [at some place outside the house]", and *father is in*, to mean "father is [inside the house]". The prepositional phrase *of his cupboard* then depends on and modifies the adverb *out*. As to *on his racing-bike*, that could either modify *out* as above, or it could be analysed as a separate, parallel adverbial phrase modifying *knocked down.*

As an alternative, you could treat *out of* as a phrasal preposition, i.e. a phrase that functions as a preposition. This is not possible for *out on*.

Many other prepositions can be used adverbially as well, as in *I am behind, it's over, she fell down*... There is a theory that all prepositions were originally adverbs, in Proto-Indo-European.